# Syntax Error generated

Tags: python, jupyter

I am a beginner in Python, and I've just started using `jupyter` notebook.
The following piece of code generates syntax error.

```
#Getting Started with Python

##We have done
*Installed Python
*Started iPython Notebook
```

Error

```
 File "<ipython-input-9-34ece10c4b46>", line 4
    *Installed Python
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: would you mind indicating what you did in order to run jupyter? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf I typed jupyter-notebook on my terminal. The version of notebook server is 5.5

Comment: You can't have bare markdown in a Python cell, it doesn't make sense. Switch the cell type. Also note you'll probably need a blank line before the list to get it to render correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely you get confused by the cell type. Your example looks like a markdown text, but you are trying to put it into a Python cell:

[image]

Here you can see two cells - the first one is Python, and the second one is Markdown. You can change the cell type in the cell type dropdown:

[image]